# How to sort a list of strings which contain space-separated numbers?

Tags: python, list, sorting

For example: list

```
['14', '15 20 1', '17', '10 25 40 3', '8']
```

This list must be sorted in ascending order with respect to its length and, with the same length, ordered in increasing order with respect to the first number in which they differ

This is the list I expect:

```
['8', '14', '17', '15 20 1', '10 25 40 3']
```

How can I sort this?

I tried to transform the list of strings into a list of list but to no avail:

```
l.sort(key=lambda x: (len(x),len(x[0]),x))
```

The problem is when I have a list like this:

```
['10 11 12 13 4','10 11 12 13 2']
```

The length is the same but the last number is smaller.

Comment: Do you mean length of the string, or how many numbers are in the string? Which is longer: `'12345'` or `'1 23'`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def cf(k):
    t = tuple(map(int, k.split()))
    return len(t), t
x = ['14', '15 20 1', '17', '10 25 40 3', '8']
x.sort(key=cf)
```

Output:

```
['8', '14', '17', '15 20 1', '10 25 40 3']
```

Comment: Nice answer @GWW , few secs ahead of me. Hope the slightly different implementation will excuse me :) +1

Answer (score 2):

You could use `sorted` and use `key` so that items are sorted according to their length and order respectively:

```
sorted(s, key = lambda x: (len(x), list(map(int,x.split()))))
['8', '14', '17', '15 20 1', '10 25 40 3']
```

A clearer example:

```
s = ['12 1 3', '1', '0', '10 2', '10 3', '12 3 1 ', '12 1 2']
sorted(s, key = lambda x: (len(x), list(map(int,x.split()))))
['0', '1', '10 2', '10 3', '12 1 2', '12 1 3', '12 3 1 ']
```

Comment: I am quite sure this is not what it is expected.
For input `['10000', '1 2']` it will return `['10000', '1 2']` instead of `['1 2', '10000']`

Comment: From what OP says, `this list must be sorted in ascending order with respect to its length`, and then by the values themselves

Comment: So `['10000', '1 2']` in your example is correct

Comment: I agree if we take the question word by word, but I am not sure that it is what he means, Barmar asked the question, let's wait for the answer :)

Comment: It appears this was right, I assumed so as the opposite wouldn't really make any sense IMO